# How do I count number of unique log messages in DataDog

Tags: logging, dashboard, datadog

I'm trying to make a dashboard in DataDog to count the number of certain log messages we get. I want to filter out duplicates though. My log messages look something along the lines of:

`Something specific happened for user with email example@email.com`

We often get multiple of these same messages for the same user but I only want a count for unique messages.

I've found that I can *almost* get what I want using the Pattern Inspector which gives me a list of unique emails and the counts for each email but it doesn't let me export that data to a dashboard. It also won't give me the count of the unique logs.

The one other similar question I found on SO was dependent on the values being in a facet rather than the actual log message so it wasn't useful unfortunately.